# How can I use waitforxpath conditionally?

Tags: automation, puppeteer

There is a button appears sometimes and sometimes it does not.

In case it appears, I should click on it, but in case it does not, I should just continue with the next steps.

This is the code I was using, it doesn't work because, if the button does not appear, a timeout happens.

```
 const continueASButton = await page.waitForXPath(
    "//button[contains(@name, '__CONFIRM__')]"
  );

  await continueASButton.click();
```

I also tried this, but it seems like its not valid code.

```
if (
    (await page.waitForXPath("//button[contains(@name, '__CONFIRM__')]")) !==
    null
  ) {
    (
      await page.waitForXPath("//button[contains(@name, '__CONFIRM__')]")
    ).click();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`page.$x`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#pagexexpression) instead. This evaluates the given XPath expression and returns an array with the results.

**Example**

```js
const elementsThatMayExist = await page.$x('...');
if (elementsThatMayExist.length === 0) {
  // No elements found, continue with plan B
}
```

---

If there is only one element that might match, you can also use an [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) like this:

```js
const [elementThatMayExist] = await page.$x('...');
if (!elementThatMayExist) {
  // No element found, continue with plan B
}
```

Comment: btw, in the second example, you meant to write: if (!elementThatMayExist), right?

Comment: @WillyCarrera If my answer helped you, you might want to [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/624201).

Comment: unfortunately I couldn't test it yet, I'm trying to solve this other bug - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61251632/cant-log-in-through-facebook-using-puppeteer-error-cookies-required

Comment: would you pls take a look? I'm stuck

Comment: Hey Thomas, i tested this but it doesn't work. It doesn't wait for the xpath to appear, but just goes on to the next steps. The xpath takes about 2 seconds to appear when it appears. Should I just use a page.waitFor? or is there a better solution? :(

Comment: @WillyCarrera You could use the `timeout` option of `waitForXPath`. Does that work?

Comment: I was using waitForXpath, but if timeout occurred, the whole process stopped. Are you saying that it is possible to say: "if timeout occurs, continue with next steps"?