# Can't log in through Facebook using Puppeteer - Error: Cookies required

Tags: automation, puppeteer

This is my code to login using facebook to a website I'm automating:

```
const loginButton = await page.waitForXPath(
    "//button[contains(@name, 'login')]"
  );
  const email = await page.waitForSelector("#email");
  const pass = await page.waitForSelector("#pass");

  await page.evaluate((text) => {
    email.value = text;
  }, "my email");

  await page.evaluate((text) => {
    pass.value = text;
  }, "my password");
  await loginButton.click();
```

Usually it works well, but once every 4 or 5 times, I get the following error after clicking the loginButton:

"Cookies required. Cookies are not enabled on your browser. Please enable cookies in your browser preferences to continue."

[image]

I changed from Chromium to Chrome to see if this would solve the issue, but it didn't work.

I also checked the cookies settings and they are enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the inputs were being filled to quickly and facebook was suspecting that I wasn't a real person. I solved it by introducing some delay between the login steps:

```
const loginButton = await page.waitForXPath(
    "//button[contains(@name, 'login')]"
  );
  const email = await page.waitForSelector("#email");
  const pass = await page.waitForSelector("#pass");
  await page.waitFor(1000);
  await page.evaluate((text) => {
    email.value = text;
  }, "casas.farach@yahoo.com");
  await page.waitFor(1000);
  await page.evaluate((text) => {
    pass.value = text;
  }, "789654123");
  await page.waitFor(1000);
  await loginButton.click();
```